# Working PHP.exe program and developing a timer program?

Tags: php, terminal, cpanel

Hey Friends
how can i develop an app which work in php.exe in my php folder and i need to know can i develop an app which will work continuously using this function and able to work it on my CPanel? 
EDIT
what i mean is,a principle one of my friend said to me to develop an page which is having a timer in it,in every 5 min it will check in a rss page for looking is there any change or new item is added or not?if we develop some thing like this it is difficult for us to work the php program again and again right??so i need some thing like that, and i need help in that

Comment: I am afraid that we will need more details on what you are trying to acheive to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'er trying to develop a gui app, you might want to have a look at [winbinder](http://winbinder.org/) or [php-gtk](http://gtk.php.net/).

Ig you're asking how to write a program....then the answer is a bit long to include here.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a PHP app that runs on the command line (launched by php.exe). This way, you will not have a restriction on the running time. But it will not be integrated in CPanel.

I have to admit I probably didnt understand the question completly, so my answer is probably a bit off ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
After your update, it seems that what you need is a cron/scheduler job. The cron job will call your script at intervals you specify. Google: PHP cron jobs.

If you mean periodically by "work continuously" you can use cron jobs (or windows scheduler). If you mean really continuosly, you should build an app with service/daemon functionality. As friends here already pointed out, it's a bit lenghty to fit in this edit box.